# splWOW64 hanging on print server

Tags: printing, driver, freeze

So I have a print server running Windows Server 2008 64 bit. It server up crystal reports to a variety of printers, some old, some new. That means there's a few different drivers on there. Recently we started having issues where the splWOW64 process will hang and all printing will back up. If we kill that process the queue prints normally. Looking at the what appears to be the hung print job every time we can see what printer and what report were printing, however it's never the same report or printer. We have full dumps of the splwow64 process and were told that the HP universal print driver PCL5 was causing the issue. It had been working for most of our printers for years before with no problems. So we removed that driving and started using individual drivers for each model of printer, all PCL6 if we could find them on the microsoft driver database. None of this has worked to fix the issue. It still happens 2-3 times a day depending on how busy it is. I've never used windbg to debug anything, I have below the results of !analyze -v -hang for a recent dump. It's gibberish to me at the moment. Maybe someone out there can see something obviously wrong?

```
FAULTING_IP: 
+0
00000000`00000000 ??              ???

EXCEPTION_RECORD:  ffffffffffffffff -- (.exr 0xffffffffffffffff)
ExceptionAddress: 0000000000000000
   ExceptionCode: 80000003 (Break instruction exception)
  ExceptionFlags: 00000000
NumberParameters: 0

CONTEXT:  0000000000000000 -- (.cxr 0x0;r)
rax=0000000000000000 rbx=0000000000000000 rcx=00000000004486f8
rdx=00000000ffffffff rsi=00000000ffffffff rdi=0000000000000088
rip=0000000076d812fa rsp=000000000028f708 rbp=0000000000000001
 r8=000000000028f7d8  r9=0000000000000001 r10=0000000000000000
r11=0000000000000202 r12=0000000000000000 r13=00000000ff963440
r14=0000000000000000 r15=0000000000000000
iopl=0         nv up ei pl zr na po nc
cs=0033  ss=002b  ds=002b  es=002b  fs=0053  gs=002b             efl=00000246
ntdll!NtWaitForSingleObject+0xa:
00000000`76d812fa c3              ret

FAULTING_THREAD:  0000000000000000

BUGCHECK_STR:  HANG

DEFAULT_BUCKET_ID:  APPLICATION_HANG

PROCESS_NAME:  splwow64.exe

ERROR_CODE: (NTSTATUS) 0xcfffffff - <Unable to get error code text>

EXCEPTION_CODE: (NTSTATUS) 0xcfffffff - <Unable to get error code text>

NTGLOBALFLAG:  0

APPLICATION_VERIFIER_FLAGS:  0

APP:  splwow64.exe

ANALYSIS_VERSION: 6.3.9600.17237 (debuggers(dbg).140716-0327) amd64fre

DERIVED_WAIT_CHAIN:  

Dl Eid Cid     WaitType
-- --- ------- --------------------------
   0   b68.19bc Unknown                

WAIT_CHAIN_COMMAND:  ~0s;k;;

BLOCKING_THREAD:  00000000000019bc

PRIMARY_PROBLEM_CLASS:  APPLICATION_HANG

LAST_CONTROL_TRANSFER:  from 000007fefcfa10dc to 0000000076d812fa

STACK_TEXT:  
00000000`0028f708 000007fe`fcfa10dc : 00000000`0044d000 00000000`00400000 00000000`0044cff0 00000000`76d840fd : ntdll!NtWaitForSingleObject+0xa
00000000`0028f710 000007fe`fd2ed95d : 00000000`004485f0 00000000`0000000a 00000000`00000000 00000000`00000088 : KERNELBASE!WaitForSingleObjectEx+0x79
00000000`0028f7b0 000007fe`fd36f42c : 00000000`00000000 00000000`00000000 00000000`004485f0 000007fe`fd2ff74e : rpcrt4!EVENT::Wait+0xd
00000000`0028f7e0 000007fe`fd33a879 : 00000000`004485f0 00000000`004485f0 00000000`00000000 00000000`00000001 : rpcrt4!RPC_SERVER::WaitForStopServerListening+0x1c
00000000`0028f810 000007fe`fd2ffa49 : 00000000`00000000 00000000`00000000 00000000`00000000 00000000`00000001 : rpcrt4!Invoke+0x13e46
00000000`0028f850 00000000`ff966b98 : 00000000`00000000 00000000`0000000a 00000000`0000000a 00000000`000004d2 : rpcrt4!RpcServerListen+0x49
00000000`0028f880 00000000`ff9671f1 : 00000000`00000000 00000000`0028fa20 00000000`00187c90 00000000`00003000 : splwow64!TLoad64BitDllsMgr::StartLdrRPCServer+0x19c
00000000`0028f9d0 00000000`ff967fb2 : 00000000`00187c90 00000000`00003000 00000000`00001a20 00000000`00003000 : splwow64!TLoad64BitDllsMgr::Run+0x4d
00000000`0028fa10 00000000`ff96d095 : 00000000`00000000 00000000`00000000 00000000`00187d20 00000000`00000000 : splwow64!wmain+0x1ae
00000000`0028fa50 00000000`76b2652d : 00000000`00000000 00000000`00000000 00000000`00000000 00000000`00000000 : splwow64!ConvertStringSecurityDescriptorToSecurityDescriptorW+0x19b
00000000`0028fa90 00000000`76d5c541 : 00000000`00000000 00000000`00000000 00000000`00000000 00000000`00000000 : kernel32!BaseThreadInitThunk+0xd
00000000`0028fac0 00000000`00000000 : 00000000`00000000 00000000`00000000 00000000`00000000 00000000`00000000 : ntdll!RtlUserThreadStart+0x1d


FOLLOWUP_IP: 
splwow64!TLoad64BitDllsMgr::StartLdrRPCServer+19c
00000000`ff966b98 8bd8            mov     ebx,eax

SYMBOL_STACK_INDEX:  6

SYMBOL_NAME:  splwow64!TLoad64BitDllsMgr::StartLdrRPCServer+19c

FOLLOWUP_NAME:  MachineOwner

MODULE_NAME: splwow64

IMAGE_NAME:  splwow64.exe

DEBUG_FLR_IMAGE_TIMESTAMP:  4f35fbfe

STACK_COMMAND:  ~0s ; kb

BUCKET_ID:  X64_HANG_splwow64!TLoad64BitDllsMgr::StartLdrRPCServer+19c

FAILURE_BUCKET_ID:  APPLICATION_HANG_cfffffff_splwow64.exe!TLoad64BitDllsMgr::StartLdrRPCServer

ANALYSIS_SOURCE:  UM

FAILURE_ID_HASH_STRING:  um:application_hang_cfffffff_splwow64.exe!tload64bitdllsmgr::startldrrpcserver

FAILURE_ID_HASH:  {369fae16-3854-e2c0-c756-fdab044a0958}

Followup: MachineOwner
```

Answer (score 0):

You should make a kernel dump ( see: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/244139 )

Then you should do:

1. search your process !process 0 0 splwow64
2. switch to the found process
   .process /p addr
3. list all thread for found process !process addr 17
4. find your thread
5. find ALPC handle in the stack and find a kernel object:  !handle handle
6. print ALPC port object  !alpc ob_addr
7. find a print corresponding server port

If you have done these step you must know a RPC server process which is hang your RPC request

Comment: It's a remote server that I have no physical access to, I don't believe a keyboard combination like that will work remotely. I could also pull a dump from the printisolationhost process maybe. Sorry for the late reply, the issue didn't happen again for a few days.